# How to add text inside XElement value that contains other elements?

Tags: c#, xml

I have and XML element like this:

```
string markup = @"<a href='#'>
                      <span>
                         outer content
                         <span>inner content</span>
                      </span>
                   </a>";

XElement elelemt = XDocument.Parse(markup).Root;
```

I want to add brackets to the outer `span` so it becomes:

```
<a href='#'>
    <span>
      (outer content
      <span>inner content</span>)
     </span>
</a>
```

I tried modifying the `Value` propery byt it strips away the inner element and replaces it with only text:

```
elelemt.Element("span").Value = "(" + elelemt.Element("span").Value + ")";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need replace the child nodes with the existing nodes with your text on either side. Something approximately like this:

```
var span = element.Element("span");

span.ReplaceNodes(
    new XText("("),
    span.Nodes(),
    new XText(")"));
```

It will get a little trickier if the whitespace must match what you've specified. You'd have to iterate through `span.Nodes()` to work out where to insert your `XText` nodes.

As an aside, there exists `XElement.Parse`, so your parsing could be written as:

```
var element = XElement.Parse(markup);
```

Comment: This removes the text content inside my outer `span` tag: `<a href="#">
  <span>(<span>inner content</span>)</span>
</a>`

Comment: My bad. Wrongly added `span.Elements()` instead of `span.Nodes()`.

Answer (score 1):

For the VB'ers that might come across this.

```
    Dim markup As XElement
    markup = <a href='#'>
                 <span>
                 outer content
                <span>inner content</span>
                 </span>
             </a>

    Dim newmarkup As XElement = New XElement(markup)
    newmarkup.<span>.DescendantNodes.Remove()
    newmarkup.<span>.Value = "("

    For Each el As XNode In markup.<span>.Nodes
        newmarkup.<span>.Nodes.LastOrDefault.AddAfterSelf(el)
    Next

    newmarkup.<span>.Nodes.LastOrDefault.AddAfterSelf(")")
```